# Are the records of a table with clustered index physically sorted on the clustering key?

Tags: rdbms, database

I am wondering if a table or particularly a heap file with a clustered index created on one of the attributes is sorted on that attribute.Is there a difference between a sorted heap file and a heap file with clustered index ?

Comment: It depends upon database and back-end store used. (Updating the question to be more specific about environment will likely yield better answers). But generally a key used for clustering affects the layout of the physical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a difference between a sorted heap file and a heap file with clustered index ?

Sorted heap file is a heap (array-like structure) with the elements ordered. This is what `MyISAM` does with `ALTER TABLE … ORDER BY …` or `PostgreSQL` does with `CLUSTER`. Inserting a new record into such a table breaks the order.

Clustered index is a `B-Tree`. Inserting a new record keeps the order.

The records in a clustered table are not necessarily physically ordered (in a sense that the record with a higher value of the clustering key has a higher offset in a file or tablespace).

Rather, the records are logically ordered: you can traverse from one record to another following `B-Tree` links (or direct links between pages in case of a `B+Tree`), but this still implies random disk seeks because the pages linked logically do not necessarily reside near each other on the disk.

Some databases, `Oracle` for instance, allow reading the indexes in physical order (using an operation known as `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN`) which does not maintain the logical order but is faster because of the benefits or sequential access to the pages.

There is no such thing as a "heap file with a clustered index": a table organization is either heap or clustered.